# Crazy memory leak with WorkflowInvoker while debugging

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, memory-leaks, workflow-foundation-4

**EDIT:** It seems my question suffers from TL;DR syndrome. So instead of reading the question, you may opt to see a video I've found demonstrating the issue: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xD0mRWJazis. Not shown in the video: it only happens while the debugger is attached.

---

I have an application that uses the `WorkflowInvoker` from Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0. It seems that while the Visual Studio 2010 debugger is attached to the process, each time I call `WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(...)` the process size grows by about 440 KB, until the process grows to a few gigabytes and my computer runs out of memory leading to the application freezing and the debugger crashing (my application only takes a minute or so to get there). **When the debugger is not attached, no memory leaks occur.**

[image: Visual Studio 2010 status bar showing "Loading symbols for Workflow..."]

As shown in the screenshot above, every time a workflow is invoked, Visual Studio's status bar shows *Loading symbols for Workflow...* even though it executes the same workflow. I'm guessing this has something to do with the memory leak. I tried disabling symbol loading by going to *Tools* > *Options* > *Debugging* > *Symbols* and under *Automatically load symbols for* I selected *Only specified modules* and made sure there are no modules specified. This did not help, the process size still grew steadily and Visual Studio still loaded workflow symbols.

Below is the minimal code to repro the issue. Look at Task Manager while running it with and without a debugger (careful, it'll eat up memory very quickly when debugging!):

```
var workflow = new WorkflowInvoker(new Sequence());

while (true)
    workflow.Invoke();   ////  Memory leak!  ////
```

A more expanded console program demonstrating the issue while displaying memory consumption is included below. It only runs at about 100 empty workflows per second. Try running it without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) and compare it to running it with debugging (<kbd>F5</kbd>). You'll see the difference immediately. If you'd rather not run the sample, I included the results as screenshots below.

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Statements;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static Timer Timer = new Timer(PrintMemory, null, 1000, 1000);
    static double PreviousSize;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Debugger {0} attached.",
            Debugger.IsAttached ? "IS" : "is NOT");

        var workflow = new WorkflowInvoker(new Sequence());

        while (true)
        {
            workflow.Invoke();   ////  Memory leak!  ////
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    static void PrintMemory(object o)
    {
        double newSize = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 / 1048576d;
        Console.WriteLine("Grew by {0,5:F2} MB (total {1,7:F2} MB)",
            newSize - PreviousSize, newSize);
        PreviousSize = newSize;
    }
}
```

Here's a 30-second run of the program without and with debugging:

[image: The included sample application running for 30 seconds without a debugger on the left, showing a steady memory footprint of 33 MB, and with a debugger on the right showing a memory footprint growing by 43 MB each second, reaching 1.6 GB after only 30 seconds.]

As you can see, the memory grows by around 43 MB every seconds. I must be able to run my application under the debugger. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I've opened a Connect bug for this issue [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765683).

**EDIT:** Well that was a bust. Apparently Connect is only for the latest and greatest. VS2012 has RTMed a whole ten minutes ago but connect isn't accepting any feedback for VS2010 anymore. My next stop: [a post on the WF4 forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/wfprerelease/thread/ec1f1851-44b4-4566-9e90-60643c0e950d). Fingers crossed.

Comment: I think the problem is that VS' debugger doesn't garbage collect normally like a non-attached process would. I tried reproducing this scenario on my machine but the memory stayed constant the entire time, with and without VS attached. Do you have service pack 1 installed for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @dbam987: Yes, I do. Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 on Windows 7 x64 SP1. What version are you running? Very interesting that you can't reproduce, as I can consistently.

Comment: @dbam987: I was able to reproduce this on another Win 7 x64 SP1 machine with VS2010 SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tim Lovell-Smith correctly noted in the MSDN Forums [question I posted](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/wfprerelease/thread/ec1f1851-44b4-4566-9e90-60643c0e950d), this is a known bug in .NET 4.0 which was fixed in .NET 4.5. Fortunately, simply [installing .NET 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) fixes the issue for Visual Studio 2010 as well.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense why I didn't experience the problem. I have .NET 4.5 installed. Glad its resolved now.

Comment: Thank you! I was also experiencing a memory leak only with the debugger attached in a .NET 4.0/WPF project (although without explicit usage of WorkflowInvoker) and upgrading to .NET 4.5 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) to me and not very surprising as @dbam987 already pointer out that the garbage collector works differently when debugging than a normal build.

If you want to know about the memory behavior of your app the only way you should be testing is with a **release** build **not** running with a debugger attached. For that matter don't even start it from VS2012 without debugging, launch it from the explorer.

Given that you pointed out that there is no memory leak without the debugger I would say you don't have anything to worry about. So this only turns into a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) when you start looking for one.

Comment: A Heisenbug will, according to the article you linked, "disappear when one attempts to study it". I can reproduce it 100% of the time - it doesn't appear to be hiding. In any case, I need to be able to debug the application for more than a minute without my 8 GB of RAM being exauhsted and the VS Debugger crashing (and requiring me to restart VS). This memory leak robs me of the ability to use the debugger, which I really need. I understand that the production version of my application will not be affected, but I am still in the development phase, thus I need to be able to use the debugger.

Comment: A Heisenbug just means the behavior is different. Often it disappears, sometimes is behaves differently. In your case it only appears when debugging. How many workflows do you need to run in a single debug session that this is causing real problems?

Comment: About 20 per second. They're small workflows design to provide pluggable logic for filtering data. Despite their flexibility, they're surprisingly performant: at that speed their work is miniscule and doesn't register as even 1% CPU usage in Task Manager. Even at only one execution per second, after about an hour and a half the process will reach 2 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Give launching your workflow using the **WorkflowApplication** component rather than the **WorkflowInvoker** a try. Its setup is very similar to using the **WorkflowInvoker**.

```
using System;
using System.Activities.Statements;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Setup the sample workflow.
        var workflow = new Sequence
            {
                Activities =
                    {
                        new WriteLine { Text = "Hello World!" },
                        new Delay { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) },
                        new WriteLine { Text = "Done!" }
                    }
            };

        // Setup the workflow host.
        var syncWorkflowEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var workflowApp = new WorkflowApplication(workflow);
        workflowApp.Completed = eventArgs => syncWorkflowEvent.Set();
        workflowApp.Run();
        syncWorkflowEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already found a different solution. Though I do wonder if running the workflow asynchronously has any performance implications, considering I'm running workflows at a high rate (`WorkflowInvoker` uses special `internal` methods of `WorkflowApplication` to run it synchronously).

Comment: I just tested this on a computer with only .NET 4.0 installed and unfortunately the memory leak still occurs exactly like it does with `WorkflowInvoker`. It seems the only remedy is to install .NET 4.5.

Comment: I tried this same code on my work machine which only has .NET 4.0.30319 installed and it does not run into the memory leak problem. Do you have that specific version of the framework installed?

Comment: Yes, I used 4.0.30319 on Win7 x64. But I ran it with an empty `Sequence` and at 20 times per second (as per the expanded test harness in my questions). Otherwise it would take too long to see the memory leak. Also make sure you had the debugger attached.